# Reply-To header not working in Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

I am using GMail API to create drafts and redirect user to be able to review and send.

However the `Reply-To` header seems to be ignored by GMail API

My header is:

```
X-Sender: email@from.domain
X-Receiver: email@to.domain
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: email@from.domain
To: email@to.domain
Reply-To: someotheremail@domain.tld
Subject: subject
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf

Email Body
```

But when the recipient of the email hits reply button, the `From` address is used to reply instead of `Reply-To`.Tried to send the email from browser as well as fully automated via API too.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Ah got it. I must supply `Return-Path:` as well.